# How to store ERRORLEVEL in a variable?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, variable-assignment, errorlevel

I'm trying to store the `ERRORLEVEL` environment variable into a a local batch variable. But it always turns out to be `0`.

```
CALL foo.exe
SET LEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SET /A ERRORCOUNT=ERRORCOUNT+1
) ELSE (
  SET /A OK=OK+1
)
ECHO/ >> logtemp.txt
ECHO ** EXIT %LEVEL% *******************************
```

I have tried to `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%` but it always print `0` too.

`foo.exe` is generating an error and it can be seen by `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%` from the command prompt and the `ERRORCOUNT` is updated correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose your problem is not the errorlevel, it's your foo.exe.

A simple test with an errorlevel works.
`(call)` sets the errorlevel to 1

```
(call)
SET LEVEL=%ERRORLEVEL%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SET /A ERRORCOUNT=ERRORCOUNT+1
) ELSE (
  SET /A OK=OK+1
)
ECHO/ >> logtemp.txt
ECHO ** EXIT %LEVEL% *******************************
```

**Second sample:**

```
if 1==1 (
  call set level=%%errorlevel%%
  call echo %%level%%
  call echo %%errorlevel%%
  echo %errorlevel%
)
```

Or with delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if 1==1 (
    set level=!errorlevel!
    echo !level! !errorlevel!
)
```

Comment: The problem isn't to set the `ERRORLEVEL` environment variable, the if ... else is working fine. The problem is to set `LEVEL` to the `ERRORLEVEL` environment variable value so `ECHO %LEVEL%` will print the environment variable `ERRORLEVEL` for the `CALL`.

Comment: I've tested the code and it works. But probably you show not the relevant part of your script. I guess: Your problem is the percent expansion in code blocks. See the second sample

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know !VARIABLE! syntax... Works fine now :)

Answer (score 3):

`ERRORLEVEL` and `%ERRORLEVEL%` are not the same (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743).

The line

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1
```

should be

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1
```

to yield the desire answer.